# I can`t run my tests on test DB, service is undefined

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs

i try to run my test file in nestjs, i want to connect to test DB and run my service with it. My service is undefined and service.findBuId is undefined too. How can i get UserService instanse on my test file?

user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { User } from './model/user.model';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/sequelize';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(User)
    private userModel: typeof User,
  ) {}

  async findById(id: number): Promise<User> {
    return await this.userModel.findOne({
      where: { id },
      raw: true,
      nest: true,
    });
  }
}
```

user.service.spec.ts

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { SequelizeModule } from '@nestjs/sequelize';

describe('UserService', () => {
  let service: UserService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        SequelizeModule.forRoot({
          dialect: 'postgres',
          host: 'localhost',
          port: 5432,
          username: 'postgres',
          password: '@@@',
          database: 'test',
        }),
      ],
      providers: [UserService],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<UserService>(UserService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should return id', async () => {
    const user = await service.findById(1)
    expect(user.id).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be a case of `relative path hell`, yup you read it correctly. This happens when you try to instantiate a class, in this case `UserService`, but it has a dependency in the constructor for `User`. The problems is that `User` may not be accessible from where your `user.service.spec.ts` file is located due to the relative path in the `import { User } from './model/user.model';` import.

You can take a look to this article (I am not the author) where explains different `npm` libraries that might help addressing this problem [here](https://arunmichaeldsouza.com/blog/aliasing-module-paths-in-node-js).

Comment: Thanks for fast answer, but, i am sure everything is fine with my paths. My error is next: "Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserService (?, UserNavigationService). Please make sure that the argument UserRepository at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context."

Answer (score 0):

First, `service` is `undefined` because `module.get` can only get exported providers. So you have to export `UserService`:

```
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [
    SequelizeModule.forRoot({
      //...
    }),
  ],
  providers: [UserService],
  exports: [UserService],
}).compile();
```

Second, the Nestjs error is very explicit:

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserService (?, UserNavigationService). Please make sure that the argument UserRepository at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context.

Nestjs tells you that `UserRepository` could not be found in the testing module and `UserService` that depends on it can't be initialised. You have to add the repository to the testing module:

```
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [
    SequelizeModule.forRoot({
      //...
    }),
    // Make the User repository available in the module.
    SequelizeModule.forFeature([User]),
  ],
  //...
}).compile();
```

Comment: Thanks, service is defines now, but i have new error now: Model not initialized: Member "findOne" cannot be called. "User" needs to be added to a Sequelize instance.